# Attaching MS Access database to exe file

Tags: c#, ms-access

The program that i'm developing uses a Microsoft access database, at the moment the database is in the same folder as the application
but i'm looking for a way so that no one can access the database by just navigating into the folder.
I don't know if the database can be attached to the exe or what, but any help on how to go by this is helpful 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database needs to be accessible by the program, which means ultimately, it can be accessible by the user.

It's customary to store the database in the AppData folder, or in IsolatedStorage.

To help prevent users from accessing the database, slap a password on it. It's far from 100%, but it's a slight deterrent.

If this is really sensitive data, then using a Jet database is not the correct solution, and you should look at SQL Server, etc.